# How do I change the value of a global variable from function?

Tags: javascript, variables, global

What is the problem here when I click the buttons that are supposed to change the value?

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 45;
var j = " I love pancakes";
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="f1();">Click me to change number</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="f2();">Click me to change sentence</button>
    <center>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function f1()
        {
            if (x == 45)
            {
                x = 32;
            }
        }
        function f2()
        {
            if (j == " I like pancakes")
            {
                j = " I don't like pancakes";
            }
        }

        document.write(x);
        document.write(j);
        </script>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you have "I love pancakes" and "I like pancakes" and `love !== like` ...?

Comment: Ok that I love pancakes and I like pancakes is an error.

Comment: But why dosen't the number don't work

Answer (score 3):

You can change the value of these variables just the way you've done it. However, the `document.write` won't be re-run automatically. The text you see on the page won't change, even though the variables have been updated.

Try using DOM to modify the content of the page when your event handler runs.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 45;
var j = " I love pancakes";
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="f1();">Click me to change number</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="f2();">Click me to change sentence</button>
    <center>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function update()
        {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = x + j;
        }
        function f1()
        {
            if (x == 45)
            {
                x = 32;
            }
            update();
        }
        function f2()
        {
            if (j == " I like pancakes")
            {
                j = " I don't like pancakes";
            }
            update();
        }

        document.write('<span id="output">');
        document.write(x);
        document.write(j);
        document.write('</span>');
        </script>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then what do I do to change that content?

Comment: Oh I found a way and is it by adding that document.write to a function and when I click a button it will call a function to change that later calls the function where document.write is located

Comment: @Milen Baykov - No, don't use document.write as it doesn't work the way you might think. Guest has given you the right answer above ... using document.getElementById('output').innerHTML

Comment: Ok the problem is fixed!

Comment: It's much more efficient to have one document.write than several, especially when different calls are used to open and close a tag that must be closed (such as a span). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 45;
var j = " I love pancakes";
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="f1()">Click me to change number</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="f2()">Click me to change sentence</button>
    <p id="sentence"></p>
    <center>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML=x+j;
        function f1(){
            if (x == 45){
                x = 32;
            } else {
                x = 45;
            }
            document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML=x+j;
        }
        function f2(){
            if (j == " I like pancakes"){
                j = " I don't like pancakes";
            } else {
                j = " I like pancakes";
            }
            document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML=x+j;
        }
        </script>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

it uses the innerHTML property to change the content

There was also another problem:
the write function were outside the function so it's never called